# bring value member of a field from a SQL table, if the id is saved

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Button9_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim lst As List(Of String)
    ViajesExternos1.Visible = False
    Dim x As String
    x = InputBox("Por Favor Introduzca el Numero de Boleto:", "Actualización de Datos")
    MsgBox(x)
    If (Traerviajesexternos(x) Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox("El Numero de Boleto no Existe")
    Else
        ViajesInternos1.Visible = False
        Viajeros1.Visible = False
        ViajesExternos1.Visible = True
        ViajesExternos1.labelinsertar.Visible = False
        ViajesExternos1.labelelimina.Visible = False
        ViajesExternos1.labelactualiza.Visible = True
        ViajesExternos1.botoninsertar.Visible = False
        ViajesExternos1.botoneliminar.Visible = False
        ViajesExternos1.botonactualizar.Visible = True
        Panel4.Visible = False
        Button10.Visible = False
        Button9.Visible = False
        Button8.Visible = False

        Try
            lst = Traerviajesexternos(x)
            ViajesExternos1.TextBox2.Text = lst.Item(0)
            ViajesExternos1.comboIDnombre.DisplayMember = lst.Item(1)
            ViajesExternos1.combodestino.DisplayMember = lst.Item(2)
            ViajesExternos1.combovuelo.DisplayMember = lst.Item(3)
            ViajesExternos1.combohotel.DisplayMember = lst.Item(4)
            ViajesExternos1.TextBox1.Text = lst.Item(5)
            ViajesExternos1.textsalida.Text = lst.Item(6)
            ViajesExternos1.textregreso.Text = lst.Item(7)
            ViajesExternos1.textpago.Text = lst.Item(8)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
    bda.Close()
End Sub
```

My problem is when it comes to bringing data to a combo box ...

As for entering the values ​​in my sql table, I use the displaymember and the valuemember, since I am entering foreign keys until everything is fine, 1.2.3.4 is inserted for example and the user sees the names and everything well in the insertion. .

When I want to update, for example, and I want to bring the valuemember to the combo box, it does not allow it, if I put .text it brings me the value that the table has and I want it to be the name, like when I enter it.

I bring the values ​​in the try catch with a select that is in a module

Comment: Your description is all over the place but I think I know what you are saying. The point of setting the `ValueMember` is to expose the specified column or property via the `SelectedValue` property. If you set the `DisplayMember` to `"Name"` and the `ValueMember` to `"ID"` then the user will select a `Name` value from the list and you will get the corresponding `ID` value from the `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: Note that the documentation for the `ValueMember` property contains a code example that shows use of `SelectedValue`. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation first. Assume that, if you haven't read the documentation, you haven't really tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the constructive criticism, it served me,
you're right